# How to increase performance on RDP session running MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, operating-system, ms-access-2010, rdp

Friends, I need to run an Access database on a remote machine using RDP and what takes normally 20-30 minutes takes 5.5 hours on the session.  I watch the debug window and the process is terribly slow.  Suggestions?

Comment: Is the Access database connecting to external data via linked tables -- another Access database file, a database server, etc.?

Comment: It has linked tables to a back end, and is the same database that runs on a different computer but not via RDP that also has linked tables to a back end.  The back end is another Access database file.

Comment: What's the network relationship between the 3 files? You have a back-end with the data, a front-end on the machine serving the remote session, and the front-end that performs well running, I'm assuming, local to you.

Comment: I can't see remote desktop being any kind of factor here. If you actually log on and use that remote computer without RDP, is it still slow? Introducing RDP into this mix should not be any source of performance issues here. You might want to check if your "default" printer is a local printer on the RDP computer, but other then this issue, RDP does not in general effect performance here at all.

Comment: If the front end file running on the remote computer has links to the data file over a WAN rather than a LAN, it can be slow. Until we know where all of the files involved live in relation to each other on the network, I agree that RDP shouldn't make much of a difference and is generally introduced to improve performance.

Comment: Update:  RDP is not the cause.  WAN is an issue, so have moved the tables and preliminary testing shows that it is running considerably faster.